# Can't create package in IntelliJ IDEA 2019

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I was having an issue, I needed to make a package called "util".
No big deal, but for some reason I can't create a package, it's Gradle just in case that means anything.

It's a fresh install too so that's weird, the package would be called `com.TotallyNotThomas.thomas_astetic_mod.util`

Gradle file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SDUC18ZS-WSjpH7pj6tQFUbR-
J8uwIAU

Full Gradle Project ZIP: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KENRqJzBag5vuLsRMCBqMnaqPz_Yn9Cz

[image]

Comment: The image is missing. Can you describe what you tried in order to create the package?

Comment: Im editing the post sorry

Comment: This seems a bit unusual for a Gradle project; it usually follows the Maven convention and places your source code into a src/ location which can be then picked up by IntelliJ.  Can you paste your build.gradle?

Comment: Sure! I'll make sure to

Comment: To be clear: **paste the entire Gradle file into the question**.  The image is fine since it's highlighting an issue with the IDE which has to be visual, but the Gradle file actually has to be pasted here in the question.  Your Google account could disappear earlier than Stack Overflow (or whomever uses this question later on).

Comment: Ok, I understand. Im just not very used to this website

Comment: Please share `build.gradle` file not `gradlew` file. What happens when you click Import Changes? Does the import complete without errors? Does the project build from the command line `gradlew build` command?

Comment: Ive just added the FULL gradel project as a ZIP file

Comment: Why did you post SOLVED in the title? That shouldn't be done. If the problem is solved, please post an answer in the answer area below.

Comment: Then post an answer or delete this question, please.

Comment: Its all fixed, it was just a visual bug in IntelliJ. I reinstalled then I was able to make a package, even when I reimported my settings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until Gradle project import is finished in the Build tool window | Sync tab and all the dependencies are downloaded, then IntelliJ IDEA will configure the source roots automatically and they will be marked in blue in the project view:

[image: build sync]

Answer (score 0):

If you select the new -> package, once you type in your name for the new package, you have to press the ENTER key.  Not sure why IntelliJ doesn't have a save button there instead, or at least have a text that says: "Enter to save."